# page show only the files in iis 7

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, iis-7

I have an Mvc 5 application, for development I used IIS Express, everything works normally on it, but I'm having a problem uploading it to IIS 7. Still on my local machine, I'll later take it to Windows 2008. The problem is that when I run `http://localhost/Aprovacoes/` my page does not open, displays the message:
HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
The Web server is configured not to list the contents of this directory.

Enabled to be able to list files in the directory, and only shows me the files not opening my page Index.cshtml

```
localhost - /

03/06/2017    12:39        <dir> Areas
03/06/2017    12:39        <dir> bin
03/06/2017    12:39        <dir> Content
26/05/2017    17:23         1078 packages.config
03/06/2017    12:39           49 PrecompiledApp.config
03/06/2017    12:39        <dir> Scripts
03/06/2017    12:39        <dir> Views
03/06/2017    15:00         7905 Web.config
```

Configuration of access to the inetpub folder where the project publish is with access, has already been tested in iis.

I have tested with all application pools, currently the Integrated is currently set to 4.0.

My route config did not make any changes, it is as follows:

```
 public static class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.LowercaseUrls = true;
            routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}", new
            {
                controller = "Home",
                action = "Index",
                id = UrlParameter.Optional
            }).RouteHandler = new DashRouteHandler();
        }
    }
```

I have already tried adding standard Index.cshtml document to iis but it did not work either.

When accessing the Home / Index, the action will identify that there is no user logged in by Forms Authentication, and will redirect to the Account / Login, this whole process works on IIS Express.

Could you help me solve this problem?

Comment: Does this happen for only one route or any route you try ? Meaning does it redirect to the login page for other routes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are publishing your site from Visual Studio quick checks such as,

- UnCheck `PreCompile During Publishing`
- Check if your global.asax file is part of the published files

, and you may want to try one or more of the following

- Give the necessary permission to the IIS_IUSRS user on IIS Server. Right click on the web site then Edit Permissions > Security. Grant the IIS_IURS permission to

  - Read & Execute, List folder contents and Read permissions
  - Try adding the following you to your `Web.Config` file

```html
 <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/> 
 </system.webServer>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, In addition to what I performed as you are posted, I had to promptly access the path C: \ Windows \ Microsoft.net \ Framework \ v4.0.30319 and insert the aspnet_regiis -i command, it reinstalled and worked, thank you!